# Is it OK to close JDBC connection from another thread on timeout?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Because none of the JDBC operations have a concept of timeout, is it advisable to try to close JDBC connection of the overdue operation from the other thread if timeout is exceeded?

I am aware of `Statement.cancel` method, however it does not seem to work in all cases. Also, the driver that I am using does not respond to interrupts.

I think `Connection.close` is, unfortunately, the lowest common denominator that can be used to prevent resource leakage in case the database operation had ran amok.

I am aware that when using connection pooling I have to close the **real** connection object.

Comment: Are you using JTA transactions or JDBC transactions?

Comment: you will get an exception thrown on the thread that is using it. It should be ok, assuming the driver correctly cleans up after itself on the way out of the exception chain.

Comment: It's your only real option, isn't it? I've considered doing this but never gone through with it. It seems like the only way to find out would be to run it for a while and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For derby it should be ok:
http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevconcepts23499.html

According to the JDBC spec you can share Connections and Statements with multiple threads

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is, it depends on what driver you are using. But from the jdbc stack point of view, it should be ok.

Comment: @Adam. It's SQL Server. I guess db engine should handle it, because you can definitely kill a runaway db session from the management console.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak one would hope an ACID compliant database be able to take care of this :) Supposedly JDBC objects can be used by multiple threads: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevconcepts23499.html (this is for derby but I am sure SQL server will work similar).

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap that operation in a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a timeout.  It'll give you more control over what's happening.

Comment: I am aware of the mechanics, I am asking if it's OK to `close` connection while JDBC operation is taking place.

Comment: Uh, no.  How do you expect the transaction to proceed if you close the connection?

Comment: I only want to close the connection as a last resort, after a reasonable timeout has expired.